# Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc.config is not available in App_Config folder

Tags: sitecore, glass-mapper, sitecore-mvc

In my MVC project i have installed Glass.Mapper.Sc successfully but not able to see          Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc.config file App_start folder is showing following files:

- GlassMapperSc.cs
- GlassMapperScCustom.cs

Please anyone help me to figure out what i'm doing wrong..?

Comment: Glass.Mapper.Sc uses [WebActivator](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suhasaraos/archive/2014/08/13/webactivator-under-the-hood.aspx) to initialize at startup, there is no config.  What are you trying to do and what are you expecting to find?

Comment: Please see on this on Glass mapper site:
http://www.glass.lu/en/Mapper/Sc/Tutorials/Tutorial12.aspx

Comment: My bad, you are right. Did you also install the `Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc` NuGet package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amitavin,

The Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc.config file will actually live in \APP_config\Include\ as it is a Sitecore Patch config file.  The two files in App_Start will configured Glass in your preferred IoC container.

Please note that Glass is actually moving away from this approach in its latest version in favor of using a Sitecore Pipeline.  See this blog for more detail -> http://glass.lu/en/Blog/WebActivatorRemoval.aspx